# Mage registry key "_singleton/core/resource" already exists - need fixes without clearing cache

Tags: magento-1.7, error, registry

We cleared the cache via the magento admin which then appeared to stop part way through and the site died.

Have cleared the cache via ssh, changed the database cache options to 0.  Tried adding the if cache then clear cache command in php on the index page as mentioned in many posts.  The cache is, to all purposes clear.  There is no APC cache on the site.

Really need some alternative suggestions that are not "clear the cache" as it has been - many times.  Also cleared the session data.

a:5:{i:0;s:59:"Mage registry key "_singleton/core/resource" already exists";i:1;s:840:"#0 /var/www/html/SITENAME/app/Mage.php(222): Mage::throwException('Mage registry k...')

Many thanks in advance

Jon

Comment: * Compiler has been disabled also.

Comment: cache in \tmp\....magento\cache has also bee cleared

Comment: Note even though the var/cache folder was being deleted it does sometimes reappear with mage--4 or other in, even though the DB has all caching set to 0.